# ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two  `json` files called `contacts` and `workers`. I am displaying the contacts and their assigned workers from `workers` JSON like this:

[image]

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here i am stuck with error, I am unable to find whats wrong with the code.

[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-4ersvk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your `forLoop` with condition, like this -

```
if (this.workers && this.workers.length) { }
```

Problem you are calling/Binding method with view part, and it calles every time in change detection. so in first `this.workers` is empty and it throws error.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-lbutzx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Sorry, you didn't made any changes in **Working Example**

Comment: Updated stackblitz, please try again

Answer (score 1):

update your function as below:

```
 getWorkerById(workerId) {
   if(this.workers.length > 0){
     for(let w of this.workers) {
        if(w.id === workerId) 
         return w.name;
       }
    }
 }
```

and add ngIf for workers

```
<tr *ngIf="contact.workers">
    <td>Assigned Workers</td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers"> 
              {{getWorkerById(workerId)}}</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```